# Forwarding varargout in matlab non-verbosely

Tags: matlab

I have a matlab function like:

```
function [f, fdx] = twice(x)
    f = x * 2;
    if nargout > 1
       fdx = 2;
    end
end
```

I want to call this function from another function, keeping the optional second-argument semantics. However, this is messy:

```
function [g, gdx] = twiceplusinverse(x)
    % this starts to get messy if the arguments to double are long
    if nargout > 1
       [f, fdx] = twice(x);
    else
       f = double(x)
    end

    g = f + 1/x;
    if narargout > 1
        gdx = fdx + -1/x^2;
    end
end
```

How can I avoid duplicating every function call that has multiple return values? What's a way to write the following that doesn't violate DRY?

```
if nargout > 1
    [f, fda, fdb, fdc] = longfunction(some_func_producing_a(), b, another_func_for_c());
else
    f = longfunction(somefunc_like_above(), b, another_func_for_c());
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `varargout` as the output of your function and then use a comma-separated list to assign the outputs of the other function. Since you use `1:nargout` as the indices in the comma-separated list, the number of output arguments requested from your function will be passed onto the other function automatically.

```
function varargout = myfunc(x)
    [varargout{1:nargout}] = other_func(x);
end
```

Comment: Does `varargout{1:nargout}` behave differently from `varargout{:}` then?

Comment: @Eric yes, because `varargout` is undefined until you define it so `varargout{:}` fails. `varargout{1:nargout}` explicitly defines it to be the correct size based on the number of requested outputs.